# Ember Data embedded belongsTo relationship returning null

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have two models:

```
Question = DS.Model.extend

  answers: DS.hasMany("answer")

Answer = DS.Model.extend

  question: DS.belongsTo("question")
```

The json serves the answers embedded within the questions:

```
"questions": [{
  "id":"1.04"
  "text":"What is the position or title of the 1% who is being protested against?",
  "answers":[
    {
      "text":"City mayor",
      "id":"1.04.02"
    },
    {
      "text":"City council member",
      "id":"1.04.03"
    },
    {
      "text":"CEO of some company",
      "id":"1.04.01"
    }
  ]
}]
```

When I call `question.get('answers')`, Ember returns the expected array of answers. If, however, I call `answer.get('question')`, I get null. Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to tell Ember that your relation will be embedded, this is done like so.

```
Question = DS.Model.extend

  answers: DS.hasMany("answer", embedded: 'always')

Answer = DS.Model.extend

  question: DS.belongsTo("question", embedded: 'always')
```

With that being said, you might want to rethink your json structure, embedded records will cause a lot of dublicates.

Ember expects the following out of the box.

```
{
  "questions": [
    {
      "id": "1.04"
      "text": "What is the position or title of the 1% who is being protested against?"
      "answer_ids": ["1.04.02", "1.04.03", "1.04.01"]
    }
  ],
  "answers": [
    {
      "text": "City mayor",
      "id": "1.04.02",
      "question_id": "1.04"
    },
    {
      "text": "City council member",
      "id": "1.04.03",
      "question_id": "1.04"
    },
    {
      "text": "CEO of some company",
      "id": "1.04.01",
      "question_id": "1.04"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: This answer is not correct for ED since mid 2013. I added a correct answer

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `question.get('answers')` works, you just need to upgrade to Ember Data beta.10, which adds the support for relationships working on both sides.